# Profile Pic not Getting From Facebook graph api

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am not getting my facebook profile pic .
I am getting my facebook id =739615472819667;

```
+(NSDictionary *)getImage:(NSString *)idd
{
    NSLog(@"%@",idd);
    NSDictionary *imageDictionary;

    if ([self hasInternetConnection] == YES) {
               NSString *urlStr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",idd];
                NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
        imageDictionary  =  [self sendRequest:request];
         NSLog(@"%@",imageDictionary);
        return imageDictionary;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 NSString *userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", pass your ID];

// pass this String where U need, like convert URL to Image or else
```

Other query parameters that can be used are:

- *type*: small, normal, large, square
- *width*: < value >
- *height*: < value >

  - Use both *width* and *height* to get a cropped, aspect fill image

I got the output for your ID friend, example

```
https://graph.facebook.com/739615472819667/picture?type=large
```

[image]

Comment: if u have a doubt add your ID in this URL and check in browser if the image is comes or not

Comment: use this URL in depent upon urself where u need

Comment: I thing U made some mistake in this method **imageDictionary  =  [self sendRequest:request];** , check once

Answer (score 0):

It will work (Replace FbID with your FBID).

`NSString *strProfilePicURL = nil;

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"FbID"]!=nil)

{

strProfilePicURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"FbID"]];

}

imgSelf=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:strProfilePicURL]]];`